# Error when trying to tap on LongListSelector

Tags: windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I've made a JumpList (by following [this tutorial](http://www.csharpteacher.com/2014/02/a-z-grouped-list-in-longlistselector.html)) linked with a LongListSelector, but I can't redirect the user when he taps on an item of the list. I used to do it well with a simple LongListSelector as this one :

```cs
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lls_Songs" SelectionChanged=lls_Songs_SelectionChanged>
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Margin="5,5,5,5">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Duration}" FontSize="20" Opacity="0.75"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

But now I use this code...

```cs
<phone:LongListSelector
                  x:Name="lls_songs"
                  Margin="12,35,12,0"
                  Visibility="Visible"
                  JumpListStyle="{StaticResource JumpListStyle}"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource lls_SongsHeaderTemplate}"
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lls_SongsTemplate}"
                  LayoutMode="List"
                  IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                  SelectionChanged="lls_songs_SelectionChanged"
                  HideEmptyGroups ="true"/>
```

...linked with this code :

```cs
<DataTemplate x:Key="lls_SongsTemplate">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="détails"/>
                    <toolkit:MenuItem Header="ajouter à la lecture"/>
                </toolkit:ContextMenu>
            </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding songName}" FontSize="30" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding songArtist}" FontSize="20" Opacity="0.75"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

here is the lls_Songs_SelectionChanged method :

```cs
private void lls_songs_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Song _selectedSong = lls_songs.SelectedItem as Song;
        MediaPlayer.Play(_selectedSong);
    }
```

and finaly how I create my songs list :

```cs
MediaLibrary _library = new MediaLibrary();
List<MusicInfo> MusicInfoList = new List<MusicInfo>();

int so = _library.Songs.Count;
int _so = 0;
while(_so < so)
    {
        Song _song = null;
        _song = _library.Songs[_so];
        MusicInfoList.Add(new MusicInfo(_song.Name, _song.Artist.ToString()));
        _so = _so + 1;
    }
```

linked with this class:

```cs
    public string songName { get; set; }
    public string songArtist { get; set; }

    public MusicInfo(string _songName, string _songArtist)
    {
        this.songName = _songName;
        this.songArtist = _songArtist;
    }
```

and the jumplist :

```cs
private void SortingSongsListsAZ()
    {
        List<AlphaKeyGroup<MusicInfo>> DataSource = AlphaKeyGroup<MusicInfo>.CreateGroups(MusicInfoList,
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
            (MusicInfo s) => { return s.songName; }, true);

        lls_songs.ItemsSource = DataSource;

    }
```

And when I tap on an item of the list, I get this error : "This method does not accept null for this parameter". I don't understand why, anyone would help me ?

Comment: appearntly there is nothing wrong in xaml code. can you share your backend code where you are binding items to lognlistselector?

Comment: and also lls_songs_selectionchanged method.

Answer (score 0):

Share or check your lls_songs items source binding and code. from your code it appears that

```
Song _selectedSong = lls_songs.SelectedItem as Song;
```

_selectedSong is null.

in debug mode see what is the value of SelectedItem. is it Song type or something else?

Comment: When I tap on an item, it appears that that _selectedSong is null, and its type is Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media.Song and lls_Song.SelectedItem is an object and contains two childs, songName and songArtist as string.

Comment: can share the binding code sample? how are you binding the longlistselector with itemsource... Also try to bind SelectedItem of longlistSelector to some Song type property and set binding mode twoway. e.g

xaml
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSong, Mode=TwoWay}"

Comment: I'm binding items with a class where I have two string (one for the song name and one for the song's artist name). Then in MainPage.cs I had elements with MusicInfoList.Add(new MusicInfo(_song.Name, _song.Artist.ToString())); . Finaly, I sort them with a jumplist (I've updated my first post with this code)

Answer (score 0):

According to your update, it seems that `lls_songs.SelectedItem` is of type `MusicInfo` instead of `Song`. Fixing your type-casting should remove the error I believe :

```
MusicInfo _selectedSong = lls_songs.SelectedItem as MusicInfo;
```

Or [better yet](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2013/09/19/casting-vs-quot-as-quot-embracing-exceptions.aspx) this way :

```
MusicInfo _selectedSong = (MusicInfo)lls_songs.SelectedItem;
```